# How far would the car skid when brakes are applied?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, friction

> Suppose that a car skids $15$m if it is moving at $50$km/h when the brakes are applied. Assuming that the car has the same constant deceleration, how far, in meters, will it skid if it is moving at $100$km/h when the brakes are applied? Do not use Physics formulas (i.e. KE formula) to solve this problem.

The correct answer is $60$m, but I either get stuck or the incorrect answer. Any help?

What I have:

$x_o = 0$; $v_o = 50$km/h$ = 50000$m/h

$x_f = 15$m; $v_f = 0$m/hr; $t_f=?$h

$a(t)=-k$

$v(t)=-kt+v_o$

$x(t)=\frac{-kt^2}{2}+v_ot+x_o$

Comment: Do you intend for $g$ to represent acceleration caused by the gravitational field? If so, that's wrong.

Comment: No. I just used a random variable $g$.

Comment: The skidding tires are converting kinetic energy to heat in order to stop the car (normally the break pads do this).  If you don't want to use the kinetic energy equation, and the work/kinetic energy theorem, you probably can't solve this problem.

Comment: Isn't it possible to solve for the time at which the car stopped in the initial scenario? And then, solve for the deceleration. Using that information, can't we find the skid distance by plugging in the information?

Comment: If you want to work the problem the hard way, the answer is "yes".  I didn't think this through fully enough before my original answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decelerate from velocity $v$ at constant acceleration $-a$ until stopping, it will take $t=v/a$ seconds. The distance traveled is $d={at^2\over2}$. Substitute for $t$, and $d={a(v/a)^2\over2}={v^2\over2a}$. If we always use the same acceleration, then $d=kv^2$, and doubling the velocity quadruples the stopping distance.

Answer (score 0):

With twice the initial velocity, it takes twice as long to come to a hold with constant deceleration (2nd formula). Since we have that distance travelled is proportional to the time squared (3rd formula), it will take you $2^2=4$ times the distance to come to a hold.

The power of scaling. Of course, you could obtain your 4 unknows from 4 equations, but why make things more complicated than necessary?